# Using VM Scale Sets as Application Gateway Backend

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-vm-scale-set

I've been trying to use Azure VMSS as my Application Gateway backend but I keep getting this message in my backend pool details page

```
Virtual machine scale set 'vmss-name' was added to this backend pool. Upgrade all the instances of 'vmss-name' for this change to work.
```

I don't know which part of the instance should I upgrade. I've tried using a custom image and the official Windows Server 2022 image. Can somebody tell me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when creating VMSS, we can choose our Upgrade policy under the `Management` tab. If we chose Manual upgrade mode, we need to manually upgrade our VMSS whenever we introduce a new scale set model. We can use this command in the CloudShell to manually update a VM in the VMSS.

```
Update-AzVmssInstance -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -VMScaleSetName "myScaleSet" -InstanceId instanceId
```

If we choose Automatic upgrade mode, our VMSS will automatically update itself whenever we introduce a new scale set model.

Please see the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#how-to-bring-vms-up-to-date-with-the-latest-scale-set-model) for further details.